# Avoid function overloading with help of template

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following overloaded functions:

```
float myFunc(Vector2D vec) {
  Temp2D temp;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    temp += computeTemp(vec, i);
  }
  return temp.compute_a_float();   
}

float myFunc(Vector3D vec)  {
  Temp3D temp;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    temp += computeTemp(vec, i);
  }
  return temp.compute_a_float();
}

float myFunc(Vector4D vec)  {
  Temp4D temp;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    temp += computeTemp(vec, i);
  }
  return temp.compute_a_float();
}
```

where computeTemp is also overloaded for Vector2D, Vector3D, Vector4D:

```
Temp2D computeTemp(Vector2D, int);
Temp3D computeTemp(Vector3D, int);
Temp4D computeTemp(Vector4D, int);
```

To avoid code duplication, I have come up with the idea to add a layer of abstraction:

```
template<typename T0, typename T1>
float myFunc(T0 vec) {
  T1 temp;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    temp += computeTemp(vec, i);
  }
  return temp.compute_a_float();   
}

float myFunc(Vector2D vec) {
  return myFunc<Vector2D, Temp2D>(vec);
}
float myFunc(Vector3D vec)  {
  return myFunc<Vector3D, Temp3D>(vec);
}
float myFunc(Vector4D vec)  {
  return myFunc<Vector4D, Temp4D>(vec);
}
```

However, I want to know if it is possible to avoid an additional layer of abstraction and directly decide the type of variable `temp` in `myFunc`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> directly decide the type of variable `temp` in `myFunc`.

You can use [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) to determine the type, e.g.

```
template<typename T0>
float myFunc(T0 vec) {
  decltype(computeTemp(vec, 0)) temp;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    temp += computeTemp(vec, i);
  }
  return temp.compute_a_float();   
}
```

---

<sup>BTW,</sup>

<sup>1. Note that if `computeTemp` returns by reference instead of return-by-value, the result type of `decltype` would also be reference (to lvalue or rvalue, depending on how `computeTemp` returns); you might need to use [`std::remove_reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) with `decltype` to get the type you want.</sup>

<sup>2. The expression used for `decltype` belongs to [unevaluated expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Unevaluated_expressions):</sup>

> <sup>The operands of the four operators typeid, sizeof`, noexcept, and decltype (since C++11)` are expressions that are not evaluated (unless they are polymorphic glvalues and are the operands of typeid), since these operators only query the compile-time properties of their operands. Thus, `std::size_t n = sizeof(std::cout << 42);` does not perform console output.</sup>

Comment: @shapeare - but `decltype()` doesn't compute it; detect only the returned type

Comment: @shapeare Explanations added.

Answer (score 4):

Or using `auto` instead of `decltype()`

```
template <typename VT>
float myFunc(VT vec) {
  auto temp = computeTemp(vec, 0);
  for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    temp += computeTemp(vec, i);
  }
  return temp.compute_a_float();   
}
```

This starting from C++11 (same limit for `decltype()`).

For C++98, the best I can imagine is the creation of a custom type traits to select the `temp` type.

Something like [caution: code not tested]

```
template <typename>
struct tempType;

template <> struct tempType<Vector2D> { typedef Temp2D type; };
template <> struct tempType<Vector3D> { typedef Temp3D type; };
template <> struct tempType<Vector4D> { typedef Temp4D type; };

template <typename VT>
float myFunc(VT vec) {
  typename tempType<VT>::type temp;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    temp += computeTemp(vec, i);
  }
  return temp.compute_a_float();   
}
```